# Android, Calling Activity within itself

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to make an app which have 2 main controls (along with other info fields)
1.> Next button
2.> Done button

I want to call the same activity when next button is pressed and display some other activity when Done button is pressed

Done button is working fine. But when I press Next button the app stops working. The error that I get is :
Unfortunately, myapp has stopped working

This is the same error which I usually get when I don't define activity in manifest file.
Can anyone please help me with this problem.

And finally Is is legitimate to call same activity within itself ?

Thanks

Comment: please post your code and the error

Comment: yes you can call same activity. post some code and logcat error.

Comment: what exactly you write to open the same activity again ?

Comment: Intent intent= getIntent();
                finish();
                startActivity(intent);

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think this should work

```
Intent i= new Intent(ActivityA.this,ActivityA.class);
```

Comment: Is this smart enough to not open another instance, but just show the existing activity?

Answer (score 10):

You can use `Intent flags` to call the activity again. In the `button` click

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
Intent intent= new Intent(this,SameClass.class); 
startActivity(intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT));
```

Comment: Is this smart enough to not open another instance, but just show the existing activity?

Answer (score 2):

**Try this**

```
Intent intent= getIntent();
            finish();
            startActivity(intent);
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to call the Activity within itself?

You can do following things:

**1.** You can **reset** data on **next button click**.

**2.** You can **hide view or make visible** on **next button click**.

Clear your **requirements** and show your code to check why the **error** `Unfortunately, myapp has stopped working` is coming.

Answer (score 0):

Use TabGroupactivity

In the next button onclick write

```
public void next(View v) {      

    Intent next= new Intent(getParent(), next.class);
    TabGroupActivity parentActivity = (TabGroupActivity) getParent();
    parentActivity.startChildActivity("next", next);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent i= new Intent(ActivityA.this,ActivityA.class);
startActivity(i);
```

or

```
startActivity(new Intent(ActivityA.this,ActivityA.class));
```