# Can an Android activity call itself?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

When creating a new Intent to start a new activity, is it possible for an activity to call itself and is this good program technique. For example, let's  say I have a template for an activity and to avoid making 10 different activities, would it be handy to have the same activity call itself?

Comment: Yes you can but this is not good technique...

Comment: @CapDroid is there a reason why?

Comment: @IllegalArgument first tell me why you want call same activity again ?

Comment: @CapDroid I had a situation where I needed to pass a new bundle to oncreate where I could control the view's inflated via xml based on bundle's content. Visibility stuffs with buttons

Comment: @IllegalArgument you can also do same thing without call new activity, just refresh your view, visible/invisible view...etc

Comment: @IllegalArgument Let's say I want to read from an xml file retrieved from a server. Different xml files have different number of classes and thus it is unpredictable how many layers (therefore how many activities) there are prior to compiling

Comment: @CapDroid . I want to pass values from one instance to the other. Hence the confusion :)

Comment: @user3774329 ask new question.

Comment: possible Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11011277/android-calling-activity-within-itself

Comment: @TAsk I was talking more technically rather than in terms of actual code. I checked that one out before and it didn't answer my question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes it is. If your requirement are like that then there is no harm in doing that. If you use this then dont forget to call finish(). finish() will remove the activity from backstack so when you press back you dont return to previous instance of same activity.

```
startActivity(new Intent(MyClass.this,MyClass.class));
finish();
```

Comment: Its just normal class and use of it is the same :)

Comment: @user3455363 yes, but think about the back button. I was worried that if the user presses the back button it will just reload the same activity

Comment: @user3455363 for such cases dont call finish()

Answer (score 4):

Yes You can do that, but then you should consider onBackPressed() behaviour as you dont want same activity comes up from your stack when user keeps on pressing back.
you may use intent.setFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP ); to make sure only one instance is created of same activity.

Comment: Interesting. So with that method the user can press the back button and it'll go back to the previous version of the activity

Comment: when you call 
intent.setFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP );
it will simply check if same activity is in the stack then finish that and start new. so always you have single activity in stack